# The probability of a certain number of trials before a defective object is selected

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A box contains 20 items of which 4 are defective.
>
> Joshua draws one item after another with replacement until he gets a defective one.
>
> What is the probability that the number of trials before Joshua gets a defective item is 3?
>
> (Answer:$\frac{4}{625}$)

I thought it was a geometric distribution.

My answer: $P(X=x) = {\theta}(1-\theta)^{x-1}$

$\theta = \frac{4}{20} = \frac{1}{5}$

$P(X=3) = (\frac{1}{5})(\frac{4}{5})^{3-1} = (\frac{1}{5})(\frac{4}{5})^2 = \frac{16}{125}$

Am I using the wrong distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $\frac4{625}$ is the probability that Joshua needs **four** trials to get his first **non-defective** item, not the probability that he needs three trials to get his first defective item (hence, your textbook is making **two** mistakes to solve the same (elementary) exercise...).

Comment: Yeah. That's what I thought. They used $(\frac{4}{5})(\frac{1}{5})^{4-1}$ which is basically the complete opposite of the right answer. I just wanted to clear up that I'm not the one making mistakes

Comment: Not a textbook though. Just these tutorials that my lecturer made up based on past exams and clearly didn't put much effort into error checking them ^^)